# Как создать веб-сервис на питоне? (И ещё несколько небольших вопросов)

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-программирование, многопоточность, websocket

есть задачка следующего содержания:

> Реализовать на Python веб-сервис (с постановкой задач в очередь — предусмотреть возможность множественных параллельных запросов), возвращающий запакованный в формат «protobuf», предварительно сжатый при помощи gzip, список пикселей, окрашенного (в зависимости от номера итерации «вылета» точки) множества Мандельброта, для указанного положения наблюдателя (Re и Im на плоскости) и уровня увеличения (размер массива 500x500). Область и zoom передаются при помощи GET параметров (`:8082/?position=0.2,0.3&zoom=2`).
>
> Результат до упаковки должен являться кортежем триплетов (RGB).

> Пример (запрос/ответ):
>
> `:8082/?task=create&position=0.2,0.3&zoom=2`
>
> `{'status’: 'working’, 'task_id’: '43031b39-7e84-44fd-9569-cd7f88f2dd9c’}`
>
> `:8082/?task=check&task_id=43031b39-7e84-44fd-9569-cd7f88f2dd9c`
>
> `{'status’: 'working’}`
>
> `:8082/?task=check&task_id=43031b39-7e84-44fd-9569-cd7f88f2dd9c`
>
> `{'status’: 'working’}`
>
> `:8082/?task=check&task_id=43031b39-7e84-44fd-9569-cd7f88f2dd9c`
>
> `{'status’: 'done’}`
>
> `:8082/?task=get&task_id=43031b39-7e84-44fd-9569-cd7f88f2dd9c`
>
> `[PROTOBUF PACKED DATA]`

Всё, что касается самого множества Мандельброта, я знаю. Вопрос состоит в том, какую литературу стоит почитать, чтобы подогнать по уровню знаний всё остальное? Особенно интересует информация по веб-сервисам (вообще не могу разобраться, как это должно быть организовано и что для этого нужно).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

качай сервер например tornado, создавай default.py, и вперед!!! а это что в ВУЗе такое задание дали?

hello world на tornado

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: @johniek_comp, нет, на собеседовании) 
Допустим, сервер я скачаю, как работа с ним будет выглядеть в самом питоне? Мне бы почитать на эту тему что-нибудь. Ну и если есть хорошие статьи/книги по поводу многопоточности, gzip и protobuf, то тое было бы неплохо. Но какую-то информацию на эти темы в понятном формате я нашёл, а вот с работой с сервером - пока не особо.

Comment: обновил ответ